# HTTP status was '406 Not Acceptable'

Tags: r

I am trying to figure out why the following:

```
url <- "http://www.fec.gov/pubrec/fe2014/federalelections2014.xls"

tf <- tempfile()

download.file(url, destfile = tf)
```

returns the error:

```
trying URL 'http://www.fec.gov/pubrec/fe2014/federalelections2014.xls'
Error in download.file(url, destfile = tf) : 
cannot open URL 'http://www.fec.gov/pubrec/fe2014/federalelections2014.xls'
In addition: Warning message:
In download.file(url, destfile = tf) :
cannot open: HTTP status was '406 Not Acceptable'
```

Strangely, it will sometimes work initially but then eventually starts returning the above.

I have gathered that this is related to the request made to the server but I am hoping someone might know how to fix this issue using some type of call from R.

Comment: Your backend service is saying that the response type it is returning is not provided in the Accept HTTP header in your Client request.